# Assigning Indexes to column/s?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

```
select a,b,max(c) from myTable
where a>b
group by a,b
```

my first instinct is to open a clustered index for [a,b,c]

*and here is the question :*

suppose someone is running another simple select :

```
select a from myTable.
```

will the `[a]` column will be seeked throught the `[a,b,c]` index? or it wont use index at all...? (my guess it *will* use the `[a,b,c]` index)

but i guess it wont be fast as a single `[a]` index...

so what should i do ?

create `[a,b,c]` index 
**or**
create `[a,b,c] + [a]` index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first thought is correct. The query:

```
SELECT a
FROM myTable
```

will be able to use the `(a,b,c)` index effectively. No need to add the `(a)` index.

---

As to whether this index should be clustered or not, that's a whole other discussion. Since SQL-Server allows only one clustered index per table, the choice should be made wisely. See the MSDN articles: [Clustered Index Design Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190639%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and [Creating Clustered Indexes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186342%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).